Ubuntu 24.04 kernel 6.8.0.x failed to autoinstall
At the moment I have kernel 6.8.0.41 (I guess it's the kernel after upgrading from 22 -> 24)
dkms failed on autoinstall for newer kernel (6.8.0.44, and now 6.8.0.45):
Directory /var/lib/dkms/intel-platform-vsec-dkms/2023.20.0-21/6.8.0-45-generic/x86_64 already exists. Use the dkms remove function before trying to build again.
dkms autoinstall on 6.8.0-45-generic/x86_64 succeeded for ipu6-drivers ivsc-driver virtualbox
dkms autoinstall on 6.8.0-45-generic/x86_64 failed for intel-platform-vsec-dkms(3)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.

My laptop is a Dell Latitute 9520
Do I need to wait for newer intel drivers before upgrading?
Thanks

thanks, @mchid
In the make.log I see this
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-13 (Ubuntu 13.2.0-23ubuntu4) 13.2.0
  You are using:           gcc-13 (Ubuntu 13.2.0-23ubuntu4) 13.2.0

There are also a few warnings, and then this one
/var/lib/dkms/intel-platform-vsec-dkms/2023.20.0-21/build/drivers/platform/x86/intel/pmt/class.c:168:10: error: ‘struct class’ has no member named ‘owner’
  168 |         .owner = THIS_MODULE,

gcc-13 and gcc-13-x86-64-linux-gnu are both installed

Look for your dkms log to find out more information about the errors encountered during the build. So something like find /var/lib/dkms/intel-platform-vsec-dkms/ -type f | grep "make\.log"

@mchid thanks, I've updated my answer

This question is similar to: dkms does not remove package. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I don't want to remove the module, because is used by the current kernel (6.8.0.41). I tried to remove the built version for "6.8.0.45" only (in /var/lib/dkms/intel-platform-vsec-dkms/2023.20.0-21/6.8.0-45-generic), retry a "apt upgrade", but always fails after build (it fails on autoinstall). I'm not sure to delete whole module. I tried also to run "dkms install" command directly, same thing. I guess I have to wait.

New kernel is out, 6.8.0-47-generic, problem still exists.
I've decided to remove the module (apt remove --purge), and then move the folder /var/lib/dkms/intel-platform-vsec-dkms elsewhere.
Run the apt upgrade again and it worked (without the module, of course).
I hope I won't have any issue in future without the module.
